# How to override Model in Sylius 1.4

Tags: sylius

I want to add new field (type) on Customer in Sylius 1.4
I use doc to override Model, but it's not working.

src\Entity\Customer\Customer.php

```
<?php

declare(strict_types=1);

namespace App\Entity\Customer;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping\MappedSuperclass;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping\Table;
use Sylius\Component\Core\Model\Customer as BaseCustomer;

/**
 * @MappedSuperclass
 * @Table(name="sylius_customer")
 */
class Customer extends BaseCustomer
{

    /** @var string */
    protected $type = 'i';

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function getType(): string
    {
        return $this->type;
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function setType(?string $type): void
    {
        $this->type = $type;
    }

}
```

src\Resources\config\doctrine\Customer.orm.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<doctrine-mapping xmlns="http://doctrine-project.org/schemas/orm/doctrine-mapping"
                  xmlns:gedmo="http://gediminasm.org/schemas/orm/doctrine-extensions-mapping"
                  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
                  xsi:schemaLocation="http://doctrine-project.org/schemas/orm/doctrine-mapping
                                      http://doctrine-project.org/schemas/orm/doctrine-mapping.xsd">

    <mapped-superclass name="App\Entity\Customer" table="sylius_customer">

        <field name="type" column="type" type="string" length="1">
            <options>
                <option name="default">i</option>
            </options>
        </field>

    </mapped-superclass>

</doctrine-mapping>
```

config\packages\_sylius.yaml (no change)

```
sylius_customer:
    resources:
        customer:
            classes:
                model: App\Entity\Customer\Customer
```

Finally, use : php bin/console make:migration

```
 [WARNING] No database changes were detected.


 The database schema and the application mapping information are already in sync.
```

What is false ?

Answer (score 0):

Try to change `@MappedSuperclass` in class definition to `@Entity`. If doesn't work, in `Customer.orm.xml` change `mapped-superclass` to `entity`

Comment: It doesn't work, again "No database changes were detected"

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to implement the CustomerInterface

```
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping\MappedSuperclass;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping\Table;
use Sylius\Component\Core\Model\Customer as BaseCustomer;
use Sylius\Component\Core\Model\CustomerInterface;

/**
 * @MappedSuperclass
 * @Table(name="sylius_customer")
 */
class Customer extends BaseCustomer implements CustomerInterface
{ 
/*...*/
```